# Rounding error of matrix multiplication when one of the matrices is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, floating-point, rounding-error, scientific-notation

I am studying Scientific computing from Biswa Nath Datta's Numerical Linear Algebra and Applications and there is a corollary after explaining matrix multiplication rounding error described below.
if $A \in R^{n*n}$ and $Q \in R^{n*n}$ is orthogonal then 
$||fl(QA)-QA||_f \leq n \mu||A||_f$ 
the older version of book mentioned the proof is in wilkinson 1965 but i didn't find anyhting related there.I am struggling on this for some weeks and i don't undestand it or can success in proving it i was wondering if anyone knows any relatable hints.
thanks.

Comment: Could you write a little more on your efforts? At some critical point you need to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  Try first with the multiplication errors alone, later perhaps showing that the summation errors are smaller than the multiplication errors, or of a similar size.

Comment: In the book most used procedure is just prove $A \le B$ and then use Cauchy-Schwarz to convert the inequality to normal form. my most struggle is the connection between orthogonality and rounding error and how to eliminate $Q$ in the process. all the rounding errors in the book are derived from $fl(a*b) - a*b \le \mu$

Comment: That last is incomplete. Floating point is about relative error, fixed point gives you absolute errors. So it should be $|fl(a·b)-a·b|\le \mu|a|·|b|$. In the summation that gives $fl(\vec a^T\vec b)-\vec a^T\vec b\le \mu\sum|a_k||b_k|\le\mu\|\vec a\|_2\|\vec b\|_2$. Then apply this to the matrix product.

Comment: yes, you are right I made a little mistake there. But yet I don't understand how orthogonality of matrix Q will eliminate it in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main contributions, the multiplication error
$$
|fl(q·a)-q·a|\le \mu|q|·|a|
$$
generalizes to the error of the scalar product as
$$
|fl(\langle q,a\rangle) - ⟨q,a⟩|\le\mu⟨|q|,|a|⟩
$$
ignoring the errors that occur during addition, or integrating them into the error of FMA (fused multiply-add) operations.  By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
⟨|q|,|a|⟩\le\|q\|_2\|a\|_2
$$
If $q$ is the row or column of an orthogonal matrix, then its norm is one.

The Frobenius norm is the square root over the square sum over all matrix entries. The matrix entries of the error difference $fl(QA)-QA$ have all the form $\delta ⟨|q|,|a|⟩$, with $|\delta|\le \mu$. Each column $a_{:,k}$ of $A$ occurs $n$ times in the product entries, so
$$
\|fl(QA)-QA\|_F^2
\le\sum_{i,k} \delta_{i,k}^2⟨|q_{i,:}|,|a_{:,k}|⟩^2
\le n\mu^2\sum_k\|a_{:,k}\|_2^2=n\mu^2\|A\|_F^2
$$
This gives the even smaller bound
$$
\|fl(QA)-QA\|_F\le\sqrt{n}\mu\|A\|_F
$$

Comment: thank you very much. my mistake was that I thought orthogonal matrix isn't orthonormal because the book defined orthogonality in many different ways.

Comment: Yes, that is not logical, the rows of an orthogonal matrix form an orthonormal basis. But it is frequently used, so a short simple designation will prevail over a longer, more exact one.